# ob-ipython error

Tags: org-mode, ipython

I have Installed from Melpa ob-ipython on Ubuntu Xenial with Emacs 24. If I try to evaluate a source code like:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC ipython :session
%matplotlib inline
importmatplotlib.pyplot as plt
inport numpy as np
#+END_SRC
```

I get the following error:

```
No org-babel-execute function for ipython
```

What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like adding `(package-initialize) (require 'ob-ipython)` to my `.emacs` solved the problem!

Answer (score 2):

You need to update `org-babel-load-languages`. Try this:

```
(org-babel-do-load-languages 'org-babel-load-languages 
                             '((emacs-lisp . t)
                               (ipython . t)))
```

This is described in the [Org Manual](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Languages)

Comment: I got an initialization error while loading `.emacs`: `File error: Cannot open load file, no such file or directory, ob-ipython`

Comment: Can you post a minimum working example of an init file that recreates your problem?

Comment: It looks like adding `(package-initialize)
(require 'ob-ipython)` solved the problem!